# What kind of problems is DQN algorithm good and bad for?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, dqn, applications

I know this is a general question, but I'm just looking for intuition. What are the characteristics of problems (in terms of state-space, action-space, environment, or anything else you can think of) that are well solvable with the family of DQN algorithms? What kind of problems are not well fit for DQNs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't currently have much practical experience with DQN, but I can partially answer this question also based on my theoretical knowledge and other info that I found.

DQN is *typically* used for

- **discrete action spaces** (although there have been attempts to apply it to continuous action spaces, such as [this one](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/gu16.pdf))
- **discrete** and **continuous state spaces**
- problems where the **optimal policy is [deterministic](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12274/2444)** (an example where the optimal policy is **not** deterministic is [rock-paper-scissors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors))
- **off-policy** learning (Q-learning is an off-policy algorithm, but the point is that, if you have a problem/application where data can only be or has been gathered by a policy that is unrelated to the policy you want to estimate, then DQN is suitable, though there are other off-policy algorithms, such as DDPG)

[This guide](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rl_tips.html) also states that DQN is slower to train, but more *sample efficient* than other approaches, due to the use of the experience replay buffer.

Moreover, if you have a small state and action space, it is probably a good idea to just use tabular Q-learning (i.e. no function approximation), given that [it is guaranteed to converge to the optimal value function](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444).

See also [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12255/2444) and [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/6196/2444) questions and [this article](https://flyyufelix.github.io/2017/10/12/dqn-vs-pg.html) (which compares DQN with policy gradients).